# Trying to get property of non-object from drupal gt

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal 8. When I create a custom theme from Drupal gt on mac I get an error.

```
Enter the new theme name []:
> test 

Enter the theme machine name [test]:
> test

Enter the theme Path [themes/custom]:
> themes/custom

Enter theme description [My Awesome theme]:
> my first theme

Enter package name [Other]:
> Other

Enter Drupal Core version [8.x]:
> 8.x

Base theme (i.e. classy, stable) [false]:
> classy

Enter the global styling library name [global-styling]:
> global-styling

Do you want to add another library? (yes/no) [yes]:
> no

Do you want to generate the theme regions? (yes/no) [yes]:
> no

Do you want to generate the theme breakpoints? (yes/no) [yes]:
> no

Do you want proceed with the operation? (yes/no) [yes]:
> no
```

```
>[WARNING] The generation was cancelled and 

>    [ERROR] <em class="placeholder">Notice</em>: Trying to get property of non-object in <em                               
         class="placeholder">system_sort_modules_by_info_name()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">1090</em> of <em     
         class="placeholder">core/modules/system/system.module</em>). <pre                                              
         class="backtrace">system_sort_modules_by_info_name(Object, &#039;&#039;)                                       
         uasort(Array, &#039;system_sort_modules_by_info_name&#039;) (Line: 330)                                        
         Drupal\Console\Command\Generate\ThemeCommand-&gt;interact(Object, Object) (Line: 236)                          
         Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command-&gt;run(Object, Object) (Line: 964)                                  
         Symfony\Component\Console\Application-&gt;doRunCommand(Object, Object, Object) (Line: 248)                     
         Symfony\Component\Console\Application-&gt;doRun(Object, Object) (Line: 185)                                    
         Drupal\Console\Core\Application-&gt;doRun(Object, Object) (Line: 64)                                           
         Drupal\Console\Application-&gt;doRun(Object, Object) (Line: 148)                                               
         Symfony\Component\Console\Application-&gt;run() (Line: 89)                                                     
         require(&#039;/Users/kailinchang/Sites/drupal8/vendor/drupal/console/bin/drupal.php&#039;) (Line: 4)           
         </pre>
```

I cannot figure out this error. Anyone can help?

Comment: `Do you want proceed with the operation? (yes/no) [yes]: > no`? Why no?

Comment: Thank you. It works once using yes, and it generates .info.yml and .theme file.